# Trying to format bibliography as section, but hidden in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, chapterbib

I am making a compilation of articles, each of them with with its own bibliography.
I thought of using a report or book documentclass, but the bibliography of each article appears formatted as a chapter. Which I don't want.
So I tried \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}, which formats my bibliography as a section. But now it appears in the TOC, which I don't want either.

I'm a bit lost about how to proceed.
I found that the chapterbib documentation suggests "for the most control, it is better to redefine \thebibliography entirely" but I'm afraid that's way out of my league.
I would like to know whether there is another way to re-format the bibliography as a section, without adding it to the TOC.

Also, as a MWE I would have a main document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Artigos}
\include{article1.tex}

\end{document}
```

And at least one article added:

```
\section{Article 1}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{desc} Inicial do nome. Apelido,  \emph{Título do libro}, Editorial, Lugar de publicación, Ano.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide!

PS:
It would be preferred if there was any solution that did not require .bib files.
Because the articles are neither mine nor I am the only one editing them, and our collaborators use the simple format shown in the article file above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer by OP.)

I found a possible solution:
I changed to a memoir documentclass, and using this single line got the result I wanted:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}}
```

Changing the documentclass requires me to change other aspects of my document, but at such an early stage of development I think it's worth it.